# What's the difference between "$(variable)" and "$(VARIABLE)"

Tags: bash

What's the difference? And why these are working:

```
echo $LOGNAME       #prints username
echo "$(logname)"   #prints username
```

but this isn't:

```
echo "$(LOGNAME)"   #prints command not found.
```

Comment: It just happens to be the same output from both `$LOGNAME` and `$(logname)`. You can see the environment variables such as `$LOGNAME` with `env`, whereas `logname` is a command you can get info from with `man logname`.

Comment: @fedorqui: you mean that `$LOGNAME` can differ from `$(logname)` sometimes?

Comment: It can differ, as you may set `LOGNAME` as you which. Try it: `LOGNAME=blblbl; echo "$LOGNAME"`.

Comment: Both variable names and file names are **case sensitive** (file names may not be case sensitive on some OSes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`logname` is a command.
`LOGNAME` is a variable.

`$(logname)` works because logname command exists.
`$(LOGNAME)` tries to run the command `LOGNAME` which does not exist.

Read the [following useful guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/)

Answer (score 4):

`$LOGNAME` is a variable. `logname` is a command. When you do

```
echo $LOGNAME
```

you are echoing the variable, whereas when you do

```
echo "$(logname)"
```

you are echoing the result of executing the command. It happens to be the case that the output is the same.

If you do `env | grep LOGNAME`, you will see that `$LOGNAME` is an environment variable and if you do `which logname` you will see the path to the executable. However, if you do `which LOGNAME`, you will see that there is no output. `echo $?` shows that the exit status of the command is 1, which means that no executable could be found.

Coincidentally, you can do the same thing with `$PWD` and `pwd`.